# delayed_job - Performs not up to date code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job (tried both tobi's and collective_idea's) on site5.com shared hosting, with passenger as rails environment.
I managed to make jobs done.
However, it seems the plugin ignores any changes in a job class source code after first run.
I have restarted the server on every change (`touch tmp/restart.txt`) but it still ignores it.

Example:

file: `lib/xx_job.rb`

```
class XxJob
  def perform
    Rails.logger.info "XX START"

    TempTest.delete_all

    i = 0
    10.times {
      i+=1
      TempTest.create(:name => "XXX")
      sleep(1)
    }

    Rails.logger.info "XX END"
  end
end
```

In a simple controller I call:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(XxJob.new)
```

Conclusions I have gathered:

1. If I change xx_job.rb to xx_job1.rb - error on the controller
2. If I change class XxJob to class XxJob1 - error on the controller
3. If I delete all the perform method content - the old code old code is executed
4. New .rb file with class and perform, enqueue this class - works perfectly
5. If I change something in that new file's perform and run job again - old code is executed

Between every change I made a restart for the server.
It seems like Passenger or something else saves class cache.

How can I delete this cache? Is is stored on the server somewhere? (I hope I have access to it from the shared hosting)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609586/rails-delayedjob-want-to-load-newest-version-of-job-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I figured that out - several workers were running in background, each of them caught a job and had their own cache.
I didn't know how to kill them so I changed the table's name for several seconds. That killed them :)

Then I used https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/wiki/Running-Delayed::Worker-as-a-daemon as worker start, and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

If you run delayed job workers daemonized, then you need to restart them to reload the code. Also, keep in mind that each worker loads its own instance of rails.