# Delayed job: How to reload the payload classes during every call in Development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am running a delayed job worker. When ever I invoke the `foo` method, worker prints `hello`.

```
class User
  def foo
    puts "Hello"
  end
  handle_asynchronously :foo
end
```

If I make some changes to the `foo` method, I have to restart the worker for the changes to reflect. In the development mode this can become quite tiresome.

I am trying to find a way to reload the payload class(in this case User class) for every request. I tried monkey patching the DelayedJob library to invoke `require_dependency` before the payload method invocation.

```
module Delayed::Backend::Base
  def payload_object_with_reload
    if Rails.env.development? and @payload_object_with_reload.nil?
      require_dependency(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "models", "user.rb"))
    end
    @payload_object_with_reload ||= payload_object_without_reload
  end
  alias_method_chain :payload_object, :reload
end
```

This approach doesn't work as the classes registered using `require_dependency` needs to be reloaded before the invocation and I haven't figured out how to do it. I spent some time reading the dispatcher code to figure out how Rails reloads the classes for every request. I wasn't able to locate the reload code.

Has anybody tried this before? How would you advise me to proceed? Or do you have any pointers for locating the Rails class reload code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. I used `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` method to clear the loaded classes.

Add a file called `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`

```
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
if Rails.env.development?
  module Delayed::Backend::Base
    def payload_object_with_reload
      if @payload_object_with_reload.nil?
        ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
      end
      @payload_object_with_reload ||= payload_object_without_reload
    end
    alias_method_chain :payload_object, :reload
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! this works great, even with mongoid as the backend. i only had to remove the first line for it to work :)

Comment: Nice! is did something similar but as a [separate script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609586/rails-delayed-job-want-to-load-newest-version-of-job-class/7861250#7861250)  and use it together with [foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)

Comment: I don't really understand *why* but this causes my Rails memory to blow up in all environments (including production) and non-DJ instances.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.0.6, DelayedJob reloads automatically if `Rails.application.config.cache_classes` is set to `false`:

> In development mode, if you are using Rails 3.1+, your application code will automatically reload every 100 jobs or when the queue finishes. You no longer need to restart Delayed Job every time you update your code in development.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it solves your problem without the alias_method hackery:

https://github.com/Viximo/delayed_job-rails_reloader