# How to autostart Rails delayed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#readme) to create job queues such as 'mailer'

For this to work I have to run this:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development QUEUE=mailer rake jobs:work
```

But if the server crashes and is restarted, I need the worker to start running again automatically.

What would be the recommended way to deal with this?

Comment: when I run this, it blocks my shell without possibility of being canceled :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a third-party service like monit/bluepill/god/upstart to watch the process and restart it. I recommend using the combination of foreman and upstart. See here: http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote a [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903375/delayed-job-how-to-reload-the-payload-classes-during-every-call-in-development) for the DelayedJob to reload the classes for every job in development mode. Same patch should work for your requirement also.

Comment: That wasn't the question :-) However if you need reloading behavior, there's a DJ plugin for it here: https://github.com/Viximo/delayed_job-rails_reloader

Comment: @betamatt, My solution will work as `HappyDeveloper` wants to run his server and worker in development mode. In the development mode the patch reloads the classes for every request.

Answer (score 0):

betamatt's approach is definitely one way to do it if you have such a monitoring tool in place.

Another way to do it would simply be to add a script to your OS's startup which runs the `RAILS_ENV=development QUEUE=mailer rake jobs:work` command under a user who has the necessary permissions.

Here's an example of how to do it on [Ubuntu using Upstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto), but if you lookup similar `init.d` methods, or whatever is the relevant for your server OS, you'll find other ways. What you're looking for, basically, is "How to run a script on startup [your OS name]", and then wrap your command in an executable script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my application am working with. So i wrote a rake task which runs every minute(as a cron job). When delayed job starts it will create a .pid file in the temp folder. I used this to check the existence of a delayed job process. If the file doesn't exist i ran the console command through code.

delayed_job_status = File.file?("./tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid")

- This will check the existence of process. If nil response go to next statement

`./bundle exec script/delayed_job start production`

- This will start delayed job

Answer (score 0):

My solution was creating the bash script in user's home
 "delayed_job_startup.sh"
which contain

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /home/deploy/project/current/
    RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

and in file /etc/rc.local I run this script from my user

```
    su -s /bin/bash - deploy /home/deploy/delayed_job_startup.sh
```